# How to convert attribute datatype from String to Array in Couchbase

Tags: java, arrays, string, types, couchbase

I have a problem. I want to change the data-type of an attribute from String to Array.

```
{
    “id”: “trn:tarb:tradingpartner:uuid:00000464-fa72-49fe-b050-c4bf1cfd8259”,
    “partnerNumber”: “1098981”,
    “partnerName”: "AFLO ",
    “currencyCode”: “GBP”,
    “commercialPartnerStatus”: “Inactive”,
    “source”: {
        “id”: “STV0001$$”,
        “name”: “QS”
    },
    “corpCode”: “DR”,
    “subCorpCode”: “001”,
    “targetMarket”: “UK”
}
```

In the above one, I want to change `targetMarket`, which is in String currently to Array as below without changing its name.

```
“targetMarket”:[
    “UK”,
    “IN”
]
```

The problem is on the old data which is in string format and if change the attribute in java then I am getting error while retriving data from db. it can't cast from string to arrayList automatically.Because of this I have to change the old data first then I have to change the code in java. If data will be null or removed after changing the object from string to array is also fine for me.

Comment: The problem is on the old data which is in string format and if change the attribute in java then I am getting error while retriving data from db. it can't cast from string to arrayList automatically.Because of this I have to change the old data first then I have to change the code in java. If data will be null or removed after changing the object from string to array is also fine for me.

Comment: Why are you writing this as a comment and not as part of the question? It will improve the quality and clarity of the question if you edit it and add the above information

Comment: Have you tried checking out custom serialization? https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/3.0/project-docs/migrating-sdk-code-to-3.n.html#serialization-and-transcoding

Comment: Are you using Spring Data Couchbase? Or using the Couchbase Java SDK directly?

Comment: Are you asking for a N1QL query that will convert all the documents in Couchbase?

Comment: its been resolved by making the field in DB as null first and then changing the attribute to ArrayList.